# Changes display after long time

Tags: backend

Whenever I make some changes through ftp (to the files manually) the changes take very long to display. I clear the cache numerous times before it takes effect. 
I am also using Cloudflare CDN, I always enable development mode before making any changes.
What all do I have to do; like what is the right process to follow after one has made changes to styles.css etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Have you cleared all the caches?
- Have you cleared your browser caches?
- Do you have "Merge CSS files" enabled?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes.

Comment: Disable "Merge CSS files" and try again.